# How do you change which program Google Chrome invokes on a Mac?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

I am not sure if this is handled differently on a Mac or on a PC. If I click on some links on Google Chrome, it automatically starts an app. This is probably is some setting inside of Google Chrome instead of on the Mac, because if it is a different user profile on the same Google Chrome, it'd ask what to do.

How'd you change which default program to use or unset it so it'd ask you every time?

Comment: What kind of links? Which apps?

Answer (score 1):

When a HTTPS site tries to open a URL scheme that Chrome itself cannot handle (and doesn't have special modals like `tel:`), Chrome prompts to always let a site handle that scheme.

[image: Always allow www.google.com to open links of this type in the associated app.]

Checking the box will mean that type of link will always open with that app.

There is an open bug regarding the inability to reverse this decision with plenty of discussion.

- [**Issue 982341: No obvious way to undo "Always open these types of links" decision for External Protocols**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=982341).

Chromium has a CL to add scheme settings but without any approvals:

- https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2204825

  > Per {protocol,site} external protocol prompt exemptions were added to
  > Chrome in M84. This is a simple implementation of proposed settings UI
  > to clear the relevasnt stored prefs data.

You can disable sites from becoming handlers using the option at chrome://settings/handlers, but that is only an on or off choice for the entire scheme handling system.

Comment: When you say "CL", that means a changelist, which is a git branch or patch? When I use `chrome://settings/handlers`, it shows mail.google.com only but didn't show any other type or app which I am looking for...